# How to update Swing Components in Real Time

Tags: java, swing

I am programming a multiplication app for very large integers, I need to update every sigle step of the multiplication in a Swing component ( I created a JPane extended class with a JTextArea in it, then add it to the JFrame inside a ScrollPane). The issue is that this Swing component only updates once the multiplication algorithm is done. I tried using a Thread that would call repaint method of the Pane every 10 ms, but it did not work. The next is a sample of the problem.

This is the main Frame class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private Console console;
private JButton calculate;
private Calculator calculator;


public Frame(){
    console=new Console();
    calculate=new JButton("Calculate");
    calculate.addActionListener(this);
    calculate.setActionCommand("");
    calculator=new Calculator(this);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(console,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(calculate, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.setTitle("Frame");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);


}


public void writeOnConsole(String txt){
    console.write(txt);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("")){
        console.clear();
        calculator.calculate();
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame();
}
}
```

This is the Console Class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Console extends JPanel{

    private JTextArea area;


    public Console(){
        this.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Console:"));
        area=new JTextArea();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(area);
        this.add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void clear(){
        area.setText("");
    }
    public void write(String txt){
        area.append(txt+"\n");
    }
}
```

Finally, this is the Calculator class (the one responsible for calling the writing)

```
public class Calculator {


    private Frame parent;

    public Calculator(Frame f){
        parent=f;
    }

    public void calculate(){
        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) {
            parent.writeOnConsole("Iteration "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you run the program, the GUI will freeze until the Calculator class is done with the loop.

Comment: why thread? Why not use BigInteger?

Comment: How large are the "large integers"? Are you sure that any multiplication takes longer that 10 ms? (Computers can do A LOT in 10 ms.)

Comment: 10ms is a pretty tight loop for GUI updates.  First, if nothing happens, you're probably blocking/using the EDT while your calculation is going on.  Second use something like 250ms, users really won't be able to see the difference.

Comment: @SMA Actually is an assigment, cant use BigInteger.

Comment: @laune more than 1000 digits or so

Comment: @markspace just tried using 250ms delay, got the same result, app just freezes until the calculation is over.

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson hi andrew, I have read the concurrency article, but I am still not  clear how to make this work, to assist with a swift solution to my problem, I have created an example program which I posted above, maybe you could take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Console class would be

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;


public class Console extends JPanel{

    private JTextArea area;


    public Console(){
        this.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Console:"));
        area=new JTextArea();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(area);
        this.add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void clear(){
        area.setText("");
    }
    public void write(String txt){

        area.append(txt+" "+"\n");

    }
  }
```

and the Calculator class is

```
public class Calculator {


    private Frame parent;

    public Calculator(Frame f){
        parent=f;
    }

    public void calculate(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override 
            public void run() 
            {

                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(50);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    parent.writeOnConsole("Iteration "+i);
                }

            }   
        }).start();


    }
}
```

as you can see i used another thread to do the changes

Answer (score 1):

if you have a layout like a `BorderLayout` and you want to update it inside the JFrame do as bellow

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
layout.layoutContainer(frame.getContentPane());// use the frame as the border layout container
```

else you can use JFrame pack() method. The pack method packs the components within the window based on the component’s preferred sizes. it's not for updating but it updates the JFrame which is kind of a trick

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
//change the components dynamically
frame.pack();
```

or use Container methdod validate(). Validating a container means laying out its subcomponents. Layout-related changes, such as setting the bounds of a component, or adding a component to the container.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Container container = frame.getContentPane();
container.validate();
```

or if you want to update an specific component use

```
Component component = new JPanel();
component.repaint();
```

If this component is a lightweight component, repaint() method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible .

or if you want for example numerous changes happen one by one dynamically then you could use the code below which is completely different from the things i said above. for that you could use `platform.runlater()` inside another thread which deals with everything that is about to change in realtime

```
new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
    @Override 
    public void run() 
    {

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable()//use platform.runlater if you are using javafx
        {
            @Override 
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception e){}//use it in for loop where changes happen
                //do some realtime change of components
            }
        });

}).start();
```

Comment: Thank you for response, just tried all above, none work as intended.I wanted to explain the structure of the app, first there is the JFrame, which contains the Class console (extended from JPanel), this class has a JTextArea in it, which is inside a ScrollPane. Every step of the calculation generates a call to the JTextArea append method, I need the Console class to update in real time after every append call.

Comment: all of those work perfectly. but since i don't have your code i gave you general understanding. the job of applying it to your code is on you. but know that they work. but if you want some realtime changes(like displaying each character one by one inside the JTextArea) then ---> i added another code in my answer, you could check it out. basically you have to change your components in realtime in another thread. again this works as well but it depends on you applying it correctly into your code

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer please check this post as the answer(the checkmark on the top left side of my answer) and rate it up. it will be really helpful. thank you

Comment: I have created a small example of my problem, again thank you for the assistace, I understand some of the solutions you gave me , and really tried to make them work, but they didnt, probably my fault. Maybe you could check the example and give me some specific insight?

Answer (score 0):

try the update method to call paint method for maintain every change